# How do I apply the Graphhopper library for coordinates with given latitude/longitude?

Tags: java, shortest-path, graphhopper

I want to calculate the shortest route from one to many places with coordinates (latitude, longitude).

The question is now how to apply the Graphhopper library for coordinates with given latitude/longitude.

For example with the coordinates of some given cities (start place is Berlin),
Berlin, Hamburg, Bielefeld, Dortmund, Essen, Bonn, Frankfurt, Trier and Paderborn, one route is:
Berlin -> Hamburg -> Bielefeld -> Paderborn -> Dortmund -> Essen -> Bonn -> Trier -> Frankfurt

Comment: My first solution calculates the next shortest distance (without Graphhopper) and uses that place as the next start point. So using the example after getting Hamburg the next shortest distance is Bielefeld and so on. That is not the "shortest" route but one solution.

Comment: I implemented the following Dijkstra algorithm: https://www.baeldung.com/java-dijkstra see my first answer. But I do not know how to get the order of the nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution** without Graphhopper

```
public class RouteHelper {
    public static Map<String, Coordinates> globalCoordinatesMap = null;
    public static List<Integer> globalShortestRoute = null;
    public static double globalActualRouteDistance = 0.0;
    
    public static void shortestRouteByPermutation(int[] a, int k) {

        if (k == a.length) {
            double aDistanceOfRoundTrip = calculateDistance(a);
            if(aDistanceOfRoundTrip < globalActualRouteDistance || globalShortestRoute == null) {
                globalActualRouteDistance = aDistanceOfRoundTrip;
                updateGlobalShortestRoute(a);
            }
        } 

        else {

            for (int i = k; i < a.length; i++) {
                int temp = a[k];
                a[k] = a[i];
                a[i] = temp;

                shortestRouteByPermutation(a, k + 1);

                temp = a[k];
                a[k] = a[i];
                a[i] = temp;
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    private static void updateGlobalShortestRoute(int[] a) {
        globalShortestRoute = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            globalShortestRoute.add(a[i]);
        }
    }

    private static double calculateDistance(int[] a) {
        double distance = 0.0;
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            if(i==0 || i==a.length-1) {
                distance = distance + distanceBetweenTwoCoordinates(globalCoordinatesMap.get(String.valueOf(0)), globalCoordinatesMap.get(String.valueOf(a[i])));
            } else {
                distance = distance + distanceBetweenTwoCoordinates(globalCoordinatesMap.get(String.valueOf(a[i])), globalCoordinatesMap.get(String.valueOf(a[i+1])));
            }
        }
        
        return distance;
    }

    public static double distanceBetweenTwoCoordinates(final Coordinates c1, final Coordinates c2) {
        double rad = Math.PI/180;
        double a1 = Double.valueOf(c1.getLat()) * rad;
        double a2 = Double.valueOf(c1.getLon()) * rad;
        double b1 = Double.valueOf(c2.getLat()) * rad;
        double b2 = Double.valueOf(c2.getLon()) * rad;
        
        double dlat = b1 - a1;
        double dlon = b2 - a2;
        
        double a =  Math.sin(dlat/2) * Math.sin(dlat/2) + 
                    Math.cos(a1) * Math.cos(b1) * Math.sin(dlon/2) * Math.sin(dlon/2);
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        double earthRadius = 6378.145;
        
        double d = c * earthRadius;
        return d;
    }
}
```

in "Main":

```
    List<Coordinates> coordinatesList = Geocoding.getCoordinatesForAddresses(addressList);
    for(Coordinates c : coordinatesList) {
        if(RouteHelper.globalCoordinatesMap==null) {
            RouteHelper.globalCoordinatesMap = new HashMap<String, Coordinates>();
        }
        RouteHelper.globalCoordinatesMap.put(String.valueOf(c.getId()), c);
    }
    
    int[] aZiele = new int[coordinatesList.size()-1];
    for(int a = 1; a<coordinatesList.size(); a++) {
        aZiele[a-1] = a;
    }
    RouteHelper.shortestRouteByPermutation(aZiele, 0);
    
    List<String> shortestRouteAddressesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    shortestRouteAddressesList.add(addressList.get(0).getAddress());
    for(int i=0; i<RouteHelper.globalShortestRoute.size(); i++) {
        shortestRouteAddressesList.add(addressList.get(RouteHelper.globalShortestRoute.get(i)).getAddress());
    }
    
    //RouteHelper.globalCoordinatesMap = null;
    //RouteHelper.globalShortestRoute=null;
    //RouteHelper.globalActualRouteDistance = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following link provides the implementation of the travelling salesman problem:
https://www.javatpoint.com/travelling-salesman-problem-in-java

I used the solution to get the route:

```
public class RouteHelper {
    public static ArrayList<Integer> route = null;
    
    public static double findHamiltonianCycle(double[][] distance, boolean[] visitCity, int currPos, int places, int count, double cost, double hamiltonianCycle) {
        if(route == null) {
            route = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        
        if (count == places && distance[currPos][0] > 0) { // an QJ: wieso bei 0? distance mit Start?
            hamiltonianCycle = Math.min(hamiltonianCycle, cost + distance[currPos][0]);
            route.add(currPos);
            return hamiltonianCycle;
        }
    
        // BACKTRACKING STEP
        for (int i = 0; i < places; i++) {
            if (visitCity[i] == false && distance[currPos][i] > 0) {
                // Mark as visited  
                visitCity[i] = true;
                hamiltonianCycle = findHamiltonianCycle(distance, visitCity, i, places, count + 1, cost + distance[currPos][i], hamiltonianCycle);  
    
                // Mark ith node as unvisited  
                visitCity[i] = false;  
            }
        }

        return hamiltonianCycle;
    }
}
```

In Main:

```
double[][] distances = new double [coordinatesList.size()][coordinatesList.size()];
            for(int j=0; j<coordinatesList.size();j++) {
                for(int k=0; k<coordinatesList.size();k++) {
                    distances[j][k] = RouteHelper.distanceBetweenTwoCoordinates(coordinatesList.get(j), coordinatesList.get(k));
                }
            }
            System.out.println(RouteHelper.findHamiltonianCycle(distances, new boolean[coordinatesList.size()], 0, coordinatesList.size(), 0, 0, 0));
            model.put("shortestRouteAddressesList", RouteHelper.route);
```

route.add(currPos); is on a false position: The route is a very long list, thousands of entries